# Does reference type serve two purposes in object creation?

Tags: java

Suppose you have your standard java example:

```
class Animal {
// some methods and a constructor are here
}

class Dog extends Animal {
// some methods and a constructor are here
}
```

When you create a new dog object, you do

```
Dog x = new Dog()
 ^
```

The reference type 'Dog' that is pointed to has a purpose; it makes x into a reference type variable because x needs to hold a memory address or at least some bit of data that points you toward the Dog object, which is located in the heap. A primitive type would not be able to modify x to perform that purpose. So that's purpose 1 of the reference type.

However, it also serves a different purpose; it modifies the capabilities of the object Dog(). If you wrote

```
Animal x = new Dog ()
```

From my experiments, the object Dog would be able to perform all methods specified in the Animal class, but it would not be able to to perform methods specified in the Dog class. Whereas, a

```
Dog x = new Dog ()
```

Would be able to perform all methods in the Animal class as well as the methods in the Dog class. So clearly, the reference type has some influence on the object's nature itself.

**My question: is it true that the reference type serves two purpose? Purpose 1: It allows the variable to hold a memory address or something similar. Purpose 2: It modifies the capabilities of the newly created object. Or am I misunderstanding something?**

(If you would like to mark this as a duplicate or close it, I would appreciate it if you took the time to read the question first rather than closing it based on a cursory glance of some keywords in the question. Thank you)

Comment: Another term for Purpose 1: It *instantiates* the object.

Comment: `Animal x` would still be "able" to perform all the capabilities of Dog, but you'd have to cast it back to that more derived type first.  It hasn't lost those aspects just by being upcast.

Comment: Well, no, it's the `new Dog()` part that actually instantiates the object...

Comment: It's not "modifying capabilities".  When you declare a variable, you declare it as a specified type.  That variable is now of that type.  You can perform any operations on that variable which are defined by that type.

Comment: The purpose of type, whether it's `int`, `double`, `Dog` or `Animal`, is to convey 2 things: (1) what can be done with the variable and, secondarily (2) how the variable is stored.

Comment: @rajah9 isn't that what 'new' is suppose to do? 'new' invokes the constructor which instantiates the object.

Comment: If you're trying to list differences between primitive and reference types, there are definitely more. Mutability, identity, nullability, encapsulation, to name a few.

Comment: I would tend to disagree with Purpose 2. It does not modify or limit the capabilities of the object. Rather, it instantiates the object (which is Purpose 1) with the methods appropriate to it.

Comment: @JBC Yes, but by changing the reference type you still create an albeit temporary differentiation  between Dog Dog and Animal Dog. Isn't that still considered a material influence, even if it is just requiring the user to perform another action?

Comment: @JohnDoe If you had one line where you only said 'Dog x;` then you could be creating a reference to a Dog object without actually instantiating the object. Same is true for `Animal x;`. There is no limiting of capabilities going on with either declaration.

Comment: @JohnDoe No, the object is still the same underlying object.

Comment: As the other commenters said, purpose 2 does not exist. The constructor does not instantiate the object, it initializes the object. `new` instantiates the object. The capabilities of the object are not changed by referring to it via a supertype pointer. The declared type of a variable tells the _compiler_ what the variable can access. The actual runtime type of the object tells the JVM what the object can do. Variable: declared type, compiler analysis. Object: instantiated type, runtime analysis. Capabilities are not affected. Downcast the reference and those capabilities are still there.

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking it.  This operation:

```
Animal x
```

or:

```
Dog x
```

simply declares a variable (`x`) of a specified type (`Animal` or `Dog`, respectively).  That's all.  It's not "limiting capabilities" or anything like that.  The compiler/runtime can determine things like how to store the variable or what operations are permitted on the variable based on that type.  But all you're really doing is declaring that type.

If `x` is of type `Animal` then you can perform on `x` operations defined in the `Animal` class.  If it's of type `SomethingElse` then you can performing operations defined in the `SomethingElse` class.  Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that I am simply declaring a type, but by doing so I create two consequences: The declaration of the type: a) affects whether or not the variable can hold the memory address and b) the compiler will determine what operations are permitted based on that type. It seems that the type still exerts two influences, even if indirectly via the compiler.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Well, sure, the nature of the type being used determines the operations which can be performed on that variable.  But it sounds like you're essentially just describing a tautology there.  By declaring the type, you have declared the type.  It's not really clear to me what beyond that is being asked.